# AWS S3: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to download the CSV file from S3 using access key and secret provided in the environment variable. Below are my finding based on debugging.

1. One of my folder name start with `/` which is causing this issue other folder and files are working file.
2. AWS console does not allow you to create a folder with name starts with `/`. However, Cost usage report can have `/` in the report path prefix which creates that folder inside S3 bucket.
3. I am able to download the file using CLI by appending one more `/` before the folder name. I also check the Java SDK code which also does the same thing but it did not work.
4. I am able to list the files but when I try to get the s3Object it gave `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error.

I tried all possible solution but it did not work in the end from AWS JAVA SDK however it is working with AWS CLI.

Can someone provide me any pointer or reference? I tried a few solutions given on the internet but nothing works for me.

**Getting below error**

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
>
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. 
>   (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: A2C6F2F49F230E18; S3 Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxx), S3 Extended Request ID: yyyyyyyyyyyy

*Note: I am using Spring boot app with JAVA SDK version 1.11.510.*

Comment: it would be great to add the key name (path), the portion of code you're using.  It is most probbaly due to char encoding or URL encoding

Answer (score 1):

After spending two days in debugging, I found out that there is a problem with Spring boot version.

I was using spring boot version **2.1.3.RELEASE** after updating Spring boot version ***2.1.0.RELEASE*** it worked like a charm.

Note: This issue occurred only for few S3 Folder which starts with '/'.

FYI:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919#issuecomment-471451804

**Finding from AWS**
AWS console does not allow the creation of folder with name starts with '/' however Cost usage report can contain '/' in path prefix.